# Testing monadic laws using QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, testing, monads, quickcheck

Is there a library or tools for testing the [laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) of a custom monad? My current hacked attempt goes something like this:

- Define `Arbitrary1`, similar to `Eq1`, `Show1` etc.
- Define a helper type that wraps `Arbitrary1` as `Arbitrary`.
- Define a test (for example) for monadic laws.

Is any of this already implemented somewhere?

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Functor.Classes
import Data.Proxy
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function
import Test.QuickCheck.Poly
```

Define `Arbitrary1` for `* -> *` types:

```
class Arbitrary1 m where
    arbitrary1 :: (Arbitrary a) => Gen (m a)
    shrink1 :: (Arbitrary a) => m a -> [m a]
    shrink1 _ = []
```

And a helper wrapper so that we can use functions that work with `Arbitrary`:

```
newtype Action m a = Action { getAction :: m a }

instance (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary1 m) => Arbitrary (Action m a) where
    arbitrary = Action <$> arbitrary1
    shrink = map Action . shrink1 . getAction

instance (Show a, Show1 m) => Show (Action m a) where
    showsPrec p = showsPrec1 p . getAction
```

Now we can write a test like this:

```
-- (m >>= f) >>= g  ≡   m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
testBindAssoc :: forall m . (Monad m, Arbitrary1 m, Show1 m, Eq1 m) => Proxy m -> Property
testBindAssoc _ =
    forAllShrink (arbitrary :: Gen (Action m A)) shrink $ \m' ->
    forAllShrink (arbitrary :: Gen (Fun A (Action m B))) shrink $ \f' ->
    forAllShrink (arbitrary :: Gen (Fun B (Action m C))) shrink $ \g' ->
    let m = getAction m'
        f = getAction <$> apply f'
        g = getAction <$> apply g'
        k = (m >>= f) >>= g
        l = m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
    in counterexample (showsPrec1 0 k . showString " != " . showsPrec1 0 l $ "")
        $ k `eq1` l
```

And let's write a broken `Writer` monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import Control.Monad.Writer

newtype MyMonad w a = MyMonad { runMyMonad :: Writer w a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative)

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (MyMonad w) where
    return = pure
    k >>= f = let (a, w) = runWriter . runMyMonad $ k
              in MyMonad $ writer (a, w <> w) >>= (runMyMonad . f)
--                                    ^ broken here

getMyMonad :: MyMonad w a -> (a, w)
getMyMonad = runWriter . runMyMonad

instance (Eq w) => Eq1 (MyMonad w) where
    eq1 k l = getMyMonad k == getMyMonad l

instance (Show w) => Show1 (MyMonad w) where
    showsPrec1 p k = showsPrec p (getMyMonad k)

instance (Monoid w, Arbitrary w) => Arbitrary1 (MyMonad w) where
    arbitrary1 = MyMonad . writer <$> arbitrary
    shrink1 = map (MyMonad . writer) . shrink . getMyMonad

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck (testBindAssoc (Proxy :: Proxy (MyMonad (Sum Int))))
```

Fails with:

> ```
> *** Failed! Falsifiable (after 2 tests and 13 shrinks):   
> (1,Sum {getSum = 1})
> {_->(1,Sum {getSum = 0})}
> {_->(1,Sum {getSum = 0})}
> (1,Sum {getSum = 4}) != (1,Sum {getSum = 2})
> ```

Any ideas for improvements?

Comment: I think you're looking for Conal Elliott's `checkers` package. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.5/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Classes.html includes a `monad` test.

Comment: Is there any real need for `Arbitrary1`, etc? You can just have the constraint `( Eq (m Integer), Show (m Integer), Arbitrary (m Integer), Monad m )`, or `Eq (m A), Eq (m B) ... `, etc. Unless you need to store quantified constraints in containers, `Arbitrary1` is probably not useful.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks, that looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Perhaps make in into an answer that I could accept?

Comment: @user2407038 True, I mainly wanted to keep compatibility with standard Haskell.

Comment: @PetrPudlák @dfeuer FWIW I picked up `checkers` a couple of years ago and it didn't want to compile. That was GHC 7.8, I think, so I doubt the situation has improved since then. So, beware, you might have to fork it.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, since the package was last updated by Conal this July, I imagine the situation *has* improved.

Comment: By the way, I would not be surprised if `FlexibleContexts` made it into the next Haskell standard. It's one of the very least invasive extensions--much less than even `FlexibleInstances`--and it's extremely useful.