# How to write a test for StateT using QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

The StateT is in `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy`

The function inside and `m` being higher kinded makes it hard

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Test.QuickCheck

newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
instance (CoArbitrary s, Arbitrary s, Arbitrary a) => 
    Arbitrary (StateT s (Maybe) a) where -- doesn't quite work
    arbitrary = undefined
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to check using QuickCheck if the applicative instance for StateT that I write (for practice) is correct

Edit:
ok, here is the instance I want to test (supposedly incorrect)

```
instance (Monad m) => Applicative (StateT s m) where
    pure x = StateT (\s -> (\a -> (a, s)) <$> pure x)
    StateT smfs <*> StateT smas = StateT $ \s -> liftA2 (\ (f, s) (a, _) -> (f a, s)) (smfs s) (smas s)
```

Comment: That… sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: @Zeta I think everyone can search for the solution as StateT is in the Base library... but the point is, I want to test it

Comment: I'm not talking about *"re-inventing the wheel"* (by the way, `StateT` it's not in `base`). I'm talking about that you [ask about "X" (how to write an Arbitarry instance) but actually just want "Y" (how to test my applicative instance of StateT)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Zeta Ok... Question title corrected

Comment: Since I'm actually in practice mode, I actually want to know how to write Arbitrary instance for this complicated type also even if it isn't needed anyway...

Comment: Allright. Could you add some more detail on `-- doesn't quite work`?

Comment: It looks like using `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}`, I can write `Arbitrary (m a)` but I can't write `Arbitrary (m (a, s))`

Comment: Related: [Testing monadic laws using QuickCheck](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38930234/1333025). And [`applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Classes.html#v:applicative) test from the _checkers_ package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is really interesting. Indeed, it would be very nice to verify functor/apllicative/monad laws using `QuickCheck` for `StateT` monad transformer. Because this is one of the most useful applications of `QuickCheck`.

But writing `Arbitrary` instance for `StateT` is not trivial. It's possible. But actually there is no profit in it. You should use `CoArbitrary` type class in some smart way. And also couple extensions. The idea is described in [this blog post](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2016-12-14-how-quick-check-generate-random-functions.html). Having `CoArbitrary` instance for `a -> b` you can easily create `Arbitrary` instance for `StateT`.

```
instance ( CoArbitrary s
         , Arbitrary s
         , Arbitrary a
         , Arbitrary (m a)
         , Monad m
         ) => Arbitrary (StateT s m a)
  where
    arbitrary = StateT <$> promote (\s -> fmap (,s) <$> arbitrary)
```

Then you can generate states:

```
ghci> (`runStateT` 3) <$> generate (arbitrary @(StateT Int Maybe Bool))
Just (True,3)
```

And you can even write property:

```
propStateFunctorId :: forall m s a .
                      ( Arbitrary s
                      , Eq (m (a, s))
                      , Show s
                      , Show (m (a, s))
                      , Functor m
                      )
                   => StateT s m a -> Property
propStateFunctorId st = forAll arbitrary $ \s -> 
                            runStateT (fmap id st) s === runStateT st s
```

But you can't run this property because it requires `instance Show` for `StateT` and you can't write sensible instance for it :( It's just how `QuickCheck` works. It should print failed counterexample. Knowledge of the fact that 100 tests were passed and 1 test failed doesn't really help you if you don't know which one failed. This is not a programming contest :)

```
ghci> quickCheck (propStateFunctorId @Maybe @Int @Bool) 
<interactive>:68:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (StateT Int Maybe Bool))
        arising from a use of ‘quickCheck’
```

So instead of generating arbitrary `StateT` it's better to generate `s` and `a` and then check properties.

```
prop_StateTFunctorId :: forall s a .
                      ( Arbitrary s
                      , Arbitrary a
                      , Eq a
                      , Eq s
                      )
                     => s -> a -> Bool
prop_StateTFunctorId s a = let st = pure a
                           in runStateT @_ @Maybe (fmap id st) s == runStateT st s

ghci> quickCheck (prop_StateTFunctorId @Int @Bool) 
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

This approach doesn't require knowledge of some high-level skills.

Comment: :) I can generate StateT instance by using `arbitrary :: Gen (StateT Int Maybe Bool)`. I actually don't quite get the "@" sign used when generating StateT instance and in `prop_StateTFunctorId`. Is that some kind of language extension? I couldn't search it...

Comment: @pterodragon Yes, it's `-XTypeApplications` extension. You can find some info in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999199/how-can-i-get-the-type-of-a-polymorphic-function-for-a-specific-type-class-insta/43000393#43000393 There is link to haskell user guide, you can read more there. Very useful and nice feature. Brief overview here: http://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-08-visible-type-application-ghc8.html

Comment: My machine doesn't have ghc 8, I will probably check later :)

Comment: For generic testing of the monadic laws, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75255293/839733.