# How to write an Arbitrary instance for a type that wraps a function?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have this type which wraps a function

```
newtype Transaction d e r = Transaction (d -> Either e (d,r))
```

...and I want to do quickcheck tests for its Functor & Applicative instances but the compiler complains that it doesn't have an Arbitrary instance.

I tried to do so but I'm stuck at generating the random function.

Thanks!

== UPDATE ==

The quickcheck properties are defined like this

```
type IdProperty f a = f a -> Bool
functorIdProp :: (Functor f, Eq (f a)) => IdProperty f a
functorIdProp x = (fmap id x) == id x

type CompositionProperty f a b c = f a -> Fun a b -> Fun b c -> Bool
functorCompProp :: (Functor f, Eq (f c)) => CompositionProperty f a b c
functorCompProp x (apply -> f) (apply -> g) = (fmap (g . f) x) == (fmap g . fmap f $ x)

instance (Arbitrary ((->) d  (Either e (d, a)))) => Arbitrary (DbTr d e a) where
    arbitrary = do
      f <- ...???
      return $ Transaction f
```

...and the tests look like this:

```
spec = do
  describe "Functor properties for (Transaction Int String)" $ do
    it "IdProperty (Transaction Int String) Int" $ do
      property (functorIdProp :: IdProperty (Transaction Int String) Int)

    it "CompositionProperty (Transaction Int String) Int String Float" $ do
      property (functorCompProp :: CompositionProperty (Transaction Int String) Int String Float)
```

Comment: [Maybe this will be of use?](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-September/083735.html) I'd think about what are you really going to gain from such random functions, though. I'd say that some edge cases is everything that this needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Test.QuickCheck.Function`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html) wrapper to test functions. It seems to have no sense in having `Arbitrary` or `CoArbitrary` instances for `Transaction` if you only need to test type class laws for your `Transaction` type (but if you really need it, you can find [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409610/how-to-write-a-test-for-statet-using-quickcheck)).

To test laws you can write properties in the way like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function

newtype Transaction d e r = Transaction (d -> Either e (d,r))
  deriving (Functor)

-- fmap id ≡ id
prop_transactionFunctorId :: Int
                          -> Fun Int (Either Bool (Int,String)) 
                          -> Bool
prop_transactionFunctorId d (Fun _ f) = let t              = Transaction f
                                            Transaction f' = fmap id t
                                        in f' d == f d
```

Well, this may look like not as pretty and nice as you want. But this is a good way to test arbitrary functions. For example, we can replace last line `in f' d == f d` to `in f' d == f 1` to see how it fails if it fails:

```
ghci> quickCheck prop_transactionFunctorId 
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 2 tests and 4 shrinks):    
0
{0->Left False, _->Right (0,"")}
```

Comment: I see this but I would like to define the Functor properties in a generic fashion. See my code above. This way I won't have to rewrite the properties for each type that I write