# How to test Monad instance for custom StateT?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, quickcheck, state-monad

I'm learning Monad Transformers, and one of the exercises asks to implement the Monad instance for `StateT`.
I want to test that my implementation admits to the Monad laws using the [validity](https://github.com/NorfairKing/validity) package, which is like the `checkers` package.

Problem is, my `Arbitrary` instance doesn't compile. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415006/839733), but it doesn't quite do what I want because the test basically duplicates the implementation and doesn't check the laws.
There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38930234/839733), but it's unanswered, and I've already figured out how to test Monad Transformers not involving functions (like `MaybeT`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

module Ch11.MonadT (StT (..)) where

import Control.Monad.Trans.State (StateT (..))

newtype StT s m a = StT (s -> m (a, s))
  deriving
    (Functor, Applicative)
    via StateT s m

instance (Monad m) => Monad (StT s m) where
  return :: a -> StT s m a
  return = pure

  (>>=) :: StT s m a -> (a -> StT s m b) -> StT s m b
  StT x >>= f = StT $ \s -> do
    (k, s') <- x s
    let StT y = f k
    y s'

  (>>) :: StT s m a -> StT s m b -> StT s m b
  (>>) = (*>)
```

My test:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Ch11.MonadTSpec (spec) where

import Ch11.MonadT (StT (..))
import Test.Hspec
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.Validity.Monad

spec :: Spec
spec = do
  monadSpecOnArbitrary @(StTArbit Int [] Int)

-- create wrapper to avoid orphan instance error
newtype StTArbit s m a = StTArbit (StT s m a)
  deriving
    (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance (Arbitrary s, Function s, Arbitrary1 m, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (StTArbit s m a) where
  arbitrary = do
    f <- arbitrary :: Fun s (m (a, s))
    StTArbit . StT <$> f
```

Error:

```
• Couldn't match type: (a0, s0)
                 with: s -> m (a, s)
  Expected: Gen (s -> m (a, s))
    Actual: Gen (a0, s0)
• In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘f’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: StTArbit . StT <$> f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, this is what I ended up doing.

```
-- https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/explicit_forall.html
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
-- https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Ch11.MonadTSpec (spec) where

import Ch11.MonadT (StT (..), runStT)
import Data.Function as F
import Test.Hspec
import Test.Hspec.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck

spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "Monad (StT Int [])" $ do
    describe "satisfies Monad laws" $ do
      -- the types are in the same order as in `forall`
      prop "right identity law" (prop_monadRightId @Int @Int @[])
      prop "left identity law" (prop_monadLeftId @Int @Int @Int @[])
      prop "associative law" (prop_monadAssoc @Int @Int @Int @Int @[])

{- HLINT ignore -}

{-
the types in `forall` are specified in the order of dependency.
since `m` needs `a` and `s`, those appear before `m` in the list.
-}

-- (x >>= return) == x
prop_monadRightId ::
  forall a s m.
  (Monad m, Eq (m (a, s)), Show (m (a, s))) =>
  s ->
  Fun s (m (a, s)) ->
  Property
prop_monadRightId s f = ((===) `F.on` go) (m >>= return) m
  where
    m = StT $ applyFun f
    go st = runStT st s

-- (return x >>= f) == (f x)
prop_monadLeftId ::
  forall a b s m.
  (Monad m, Eq (m (b, s)), Show (m (b, s))) =>
  a ->
  s ->
  Fun (a, s) (m (b, s)) ->
  Property
prop_monadLeftId a s f = ((===) `F.on` go) (return a >>= h) m
  where
    g = applyFun2 f
    m = StT $ g a
    h = StT . g
    go st = runStT st s

-- ((x >>= f) >>= g) == (x >>= (\x' -> f x' >>= g))
prop_monadAssoc ::
  forall a b c s m.
  (Monad m, Eq (m (b, s)), Show (m (b, s)), Eq (m (c, s)), Show (m (c, s))) =>
  s ->
  Fun s (m (a, s)) ->
  Fun (a, s) (m (b, s)) ->
  Fun (b, s) (m (c, s)) ->
  Property
prop_monadAssoc s h f g =
  ((===) `F.on` go)
    ((m >>= f') >>= g')
    (m >>= (\x -> f' x >>= g'))
  where
    m = StT $ applyFun h
    f' = StT . applyFun2 f
    g' = StT . applyFun2 g
    go st = runStT st s
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `pure`, not `(<$>)`. (But I haven't checked with my local compiler, so I'm not sure.) You probably also have to turn your `Fun` into an actual function.

```
arbitrary = do
  f <- arbitrary
  pure (StTArbit . StT . applyFun $ f)
```

I'd also point out that there's not much point to making a `newtype` here. I guess it avoids an orphan instance warning? But you've defined the type you're writing an instance for yourself, presumably even in the same package, so it seems pretty benign; if it's part of a separate cabal component that people can't depend on, like a test suite, even more so.

Comment: Doesn't compile.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar No. But it does fix the error the question asked about. That's... kinda what SO is about; we get you over your current hump, then the work is back in your lap. And, if I may be blunt, the errors you get after this are quite standard, to the point that, with one exception, even the *compiler* can tell you how to fix them (and does). The remaining one has been done to death; e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52300078/791604) but also many other times here on SO, a very quick search will turn them up.

Comment: Despite the claim, this _didn't_ get me over the current hump, it merely replaced one error with another. And I may be blunt, but if the errors I'm getting are quite standard, why doesn't your code that attempts a fix doesn't even compile? On the contrary, the links in my question show that there's _no_ standard answer. Contrary to what you say, SO is not about throwing pasta at the wall and hoping something sticks. Precise, thorough, and detailed answers are always appreciated; I should know, I've written some like those.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The code in this answer does compile, once you *follow the compiler's advice in the errors it gives you* (and the advice in my link). I checked with my local compiler this time -- indeed, before I even wrote my previous comment.